# Assertion failure in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have an Assertion Failure in UIPageViewController.

```
Assertion failure in -[UIPageViewController _flushViewController:animated:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.60.12/UIPageViewController.m
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
'Don't know about flushed view <UIView: 0x15a5bff30; frame = (0 0; 768 903); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x15a5bfc30>>'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181ebedb0 0x181523f80 0x181ebec80 0x182844154 0x1877a1c40 0x1877a1da8 0x18784e9c4 0x18784ebfc 0x187852318 0x18784dd98 0x1870101e4 0x1849a2994 0x18499d5d0 0x1870270a4 0x10028b620 0x100348b78 0x100379f54 0x100168878 0x18733d568 0x1870330b4 0x1870f1a00 0x18733e71c 0x1870f832c 0x18703536c 0x18700f7ac 0x18700ed40 0x18700eba8 0x1873283b4 0x18700d5e8 0x18784ebd4 0x187852318 0x18784df3c 0x1871db550 0x1871daf6c 0x101c9b768 0x1849f0234 0x1849f00e8 0x182135e54 0x181e5d030 0x181e757d4 0x181e74f0c 0x181e72c64 0x181d9cc50 0x183684088 0x18707e088 0x10033b200 0x18193a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't know why this error is occurring. Any clues on what's causing it or how to debug it?

Comment: What is flush view controller?

Comment: I don't have an idea about flushViewController...
I haven't used flushViewController.. 
I think UIPageViewController use flushViewController method internally

Comment: What kind of view is your  <UIView: 0x15a5bff30; frame = (0 0; 768 903); ...> and what are you doing with it?

Comment: I'm having similar issues, did this ever get solved?

Comment: @kformeck Not apparently. Created a bounty.

Comment: There is not enough context in your question to come up with a detailed, accurate answer. We need to know how you have implemented your paging controller and what subviews you have.

Answer (score 14):

The direct way to run into this assert is to use cycled source for `UIPageController` defined with scroll transition style.

When the source contains two pages each one is the previous and the next for another one. If you swipe `UIPageController` containing two pages and then try to set source with 3 pages you will get the assertion mentioned above with guarantee assuming that `UIPageControllerDataSource` before/after methods allow cycled transition in case of 2 pages.

The main rules of crash-free using `UIPageController` with scroll transition:

1) set `dataSource` before calling `setViewControllers` method

2) use `setViewControllers` method without animation (`animated: false`)

3) set `dataSource` to nil for single page mode

4) don't allow cycles for 2-page mode

All these recommendations together make `UIPageController` absolutely stable.

```
import UIKit

/// Convenient subclass of UIPageViewController
@objc class AMPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    /// Turn on/off PageControl at the bottom
    @objc var showPageControl: Bool = true

    /// Array of all viewControllers
    @objc var source: [UIViewController]? {

        didSet {
            let count = source?.count ?? 0
            if count > 0 {
                dataSource = count > 1 ? self : nil
            }
            else {
                dataSource = nil
                delegate = nil
            }
        }
    }

    /// Index of the current viewController from source
    @objc var pageIndex: Int {

        get {
            var currentPageIndex: Int = 0
            if let vc = viewControllers?.first, let source = source, let pageIndex = source.index(of: vc) {
                currentPageIndex = pageIndex
            }

            return currentPageIndex
        }

        set {
            guard newValue >= 0, let source = source, newValue < source.count else { return }

            let vc = source[newValue]
            let direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = newValue < pageIndex ? .reverse : .forward

            setViewController(vc, direction: direction)
        }
    }

    override weak var delegate: UIPageViewControllerDelegate? {

        get { return super.delegate }

        set {
            if source?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                super.delegate = newValue
            }
            else {
                super.delegate = nil
            }
        }
    }

    /// Initializer in scroll-mode with interPageSpacing
    @objc init(navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation = .horizontal, interPageSpacing: Int = 0) {

        let options = (interPageSpacing > 0) ? [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : 5] : nil

         super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: navigationOrientation, options: options)
     }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    /// Set viewcontroller by index from source
    @objc func setPageIndex(_ index: Int, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

        guard index > 0, let source = source, index < source.count else { return }

        let vc = source[index]
        let direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = index < pageIndex ? .reverse : .forward

        setViewController(vc, direction: direction, completion: completion)
    }


    private func setViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = .forward, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

        super.setViewControllers([viewController], direction: direction, animated: false, completion: completion)
    }
}

extension FFPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let source = source, let index = source.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let count = source.count

        if count == 2, index == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        let prevIndex = (index - 1) < 0 ? count - 1 : index - 1

        let pageContentViewController: UIViewController = source[prevIndex]

        return pageContentViewController
    }


    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let source = source, let index = source.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let count = source.count

        if count == 2, index == 1 {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = (index + 1) >= count ? 0 : index + 1

        let pageContentViewController = source[nextIndex]

        return pageContentViewController
    }


    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        return showPageControl ? (source?.count ?? 0) : 0
    }


    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        guard showPageControl else { return 0 }

        return pageIndex
    }
}
```

The overall implementation and usage examples one can find at [GitHub project](https://github.com/iospro/AMPageViewController).

Comment: And what if you want animation?

Answer (score 3):

When `UIPageViewController` transition, ViewController inside it(ex: UITableViewController) transition will cause crash.

In my case (**crash**):

step1

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([self.tableViewController2], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

step2

Scroll the tableView while `UIPageViewController` transition.

**My Solution**

(disable scroll both target view controller and current view controller)

```
self.tableViewController1.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
self.tableViewController2.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([self.tableViewController2], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: { _ in
    self.tableViewController1.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.tableViewController2.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your `pageViewController.setViewControllers` function call inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` block if you are doing it in code.

I don't know why it works but it worked for me. [For reference.](https://github.com/uias/Pageboy/pull/111/commits/58d3c812f13e89868418c6f4cb4615527191bb16)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too when I had textfields in child controller and didn't dismiss keyboard on scroll to next controller. If this is case just add endEditing in action where you programmatically change your controller or if you are scrolling on scrollViewDidScroll delegate method of pageViewController

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle` is set to `scroll` instead of `pageCurl`.

Are you dynamically creating View Controllers and setting them on UIPageViewController? In that case, you must ensure that the second call to setViewControllers is called after the first one completes animation because of a bug in UIKit. A delayed dispatch is a quick and dirty fix, though it is not a good practice

More details here.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6554

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was using `self.pageViewController` as a member of the current view controller instead of `pageViewController` as parameter obtained in the `didFinishAnimating` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

This my solution:

```
private func scrollToViewController(viewController: UIViewController,
                                  direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection = .reverse) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  for view in self.view.subviews {
    if let subView = view as? UIScrollView {
      subView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }
  self.setViewControllers([viewController],
                     direction: direction,
                     animated: false,
                     completion: { (finished) -> Void in
    
  })
}}
```

Note: When you delete item, don't use direction as a forward. Use reverse for direction. Because pageviewcontroller does not have forward view controller.